# How to reference a method from a regular cs file in a user control ascx file? giving me errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im really new at this, Im following an example of a book I bought and I'm lost since I'm not sure if things have change in this regards, I've look all over the internet (google and here) to find the answer and nothing, deeply apologize if it has been asked before.

The thing is I'm following the code snipets from the book and to do a Balloon Shop online store, so to create a user control that will present the information for the different departments located in the database.

I need to reference a method in the user control located in the public class CatalogAccess, but is showing that CatalogAccess does not exist in the current context.

This is the code behind of the user control, where the problem happens:

```
public partial class UserControls_DepartmentsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        list.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetDepartments();
        list.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is the code for CatalogAccess:

```
public static class CatalogAccess
{
    public static DataTable GetDepartments()
    {
        DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "Get Departments";
        return GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);
    }
}
```

[image: Error picture]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your `CatalogAccess` class is defined in a separate namespace and if so then you might want to import that saying `using some_namespace;`. Also, if it's defined in a separate project/assembly then you will have to add the reference of that assembly to your aspx project

Comment: Thanks for answering, the CatalogAccess is not defined in separate namespace, in fact none of the C# codes are inside any namespace and as far as I know is not defined in a separate project either, I mean is in a separate folder called App_Code but that folder is inside the same project/solution so I'm not quite sure if that's a different assembly.